# Approval workflow not properly and i do not have test ids to check its working for now

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, approval

i have created a workflow with sharepoint designer 2013 in which multiple notification email will be sent. 1st of all email sent to initiator that form is submitted after that it will sent to reviewer to review the form when the review status is accepted then it will be sent to approver to approve the form or if the reviewStatus is rejected mail will only sent to initiator that rework required. after approvalstatus is accepted last step is to close the form. i am new to sharepoint. This workflow is not working properly kindly help me to make this happen and i also want to break this workflow in steps like reviewtask, approval task and closure task.

```
If Current Item:Review Status is empty value
    Email Current Item:Created By; Variable: Reviewer
    Set Form Status to WaitingforReviewal
    Set Variable: Reviewer to Current Item:Display Name
    Set Variable: Approver to Current Item:Display Name
    Set Variable: DMR(QA) to Current Item:Display Name
Else
    If Current Item:Review Status equals Accept
        Set Form Status to ReviewalAccepted
        Email Current Item:Created By
        Email Variable: Approver
        Set Form Status to WaitingforApproval
        If Current Item:Approve Status equals Approve
            Set Form Status to Approved
            Email Current Item:Created By
            Email Variable: DMR(QA)
            If Current Item:DMRstatus equals Closed
                Set Form Status to Closed
                Email Current Item:Created By
        Else
        If Current Item:Approve Status equals Reject
            Set Form Status to Rejected
            Email Current Item:Created By
    Else
        If Current Item:Review Status equals Reject
            Set Form Status to Rejected
            Email Current Item:Created By
```

Comment: i have made it on sharepoint designer 2010 workflow not on 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following workflow actions to achieve your requirement:

[image]
[image]

If you don’t have email addresses to test, you can use “Log to History List” action to check if the previous action is executed successfully.

Comment: why you use currentReviewStatus,  currentApproveStatus, currentDMRStatus variables i cant undersatnd? thank for your comment  i also want to add workflow history in my infopath form 2013 but i cant understand how to do it. kindly help me. i have to submit it tommorrow

Comment: These additional variable catch the original status value for relevant status column before start approval task.  We can compare current status value with original value, if they're not same, it means reviewer or approver change the status column, then we can check if the status equals approved or rejected. We can only view the workflow history in the list workflow status page. Besides, I update a picture in my above post, please check it.

Comment: i want to add submitted by this approved by this and closed by this in my form history. is there any wany to do it in infopath form